# Como evitar que o foco do input-text seja perdido ao clicar em um outro elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `input` do tipo `text`, em que posso digitar uma busca, que é executada via ajax, enquanto o usuário digita. Abaixo deste tenho uma lista de itens que foram achados em uma `table`. Ao clicar nessa tabela, eu altero o estilo da row clicada, como se estivesse selecionada, mas não quero que o foco do input seja perdido... quero que o usuário, mesmo tendo clicado na tabela, possa continuar a digitar.

Já tentei o evento `blur` mas até o momento ainda não consegui, pois não sei se o elemento clicado estava dentro da tabela.

Comment: Poderia postar o código do que você fez até agora? html e js

Answer (score 3):

Você pode colocar um evento na tabela para devolver o foco ao campo de pesquisa com a função `focus()` do jQuery.

Exemplo

```js
//evento click da tabela
$('#resultado').on('click', 'tr', function() {

    //muda a cor da linha atual
    $(this).css('background-color', '#DDEEFF')

    //tira a cor das outras linhas
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', 'transparent')

    //devolve o foco ao campo de pesquisa
    $('#pesquisa').focus();

});
```

#### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7XVj/)

Comment: porém devemos informar o OP que nossas respostas são relativas pelo fato de que não sabemos se ele utiliza um `<td>` ou um `<tr>` para seleção.

Comment: @PauloRoberto O OP disse que altera o estilo da "Row", então entendo que se refira ao elemento `tr`.

Comment: Opa, essa passou despercebido, porém seria melhor se ele colocasse o código html usado.

Answer (score 2):

Se você clicar em outro elemento, você **vai** perder o foco da caixa de texto. Isso é controlado pelo navegador.

O máximo que você pode fazer é utilizar o evento de clique da linha  da tabela (ou qualquer que seja o evento que você já usa para alterar o estilo da linha) para chamar o método `focus` para retornar o foco à caixa de texto. Mas lembre-se, haverá uma mudança de foco, por mais rápida que seja, e os eventos de foco e `blur` serão disparados para a caixa e para a linha da tabela.

Answer (score 2):

Acabei resolvendo o problema, mas esse é daqueles que se deve aparar as pontas browser por browser, pois cada um tem uma coisinha diferente... então, dito isso, aqui vai uma solução que consegui testar no Chrome 32, Firefox 27 e no IE 8.

A ideia básica é no evento `blur` do input, setar o foco para ele mesmo, caso o elemento clicado pertença à tabela.

### Chegando na solução final

- Primeiramente a tabela deve possuir `tabindex`, caso contrário alguns navegadores não conseguem ver para onde o foco está indo. e.g. Chrome
- Depois tenho que saber para onde o foco está indo, cada browser a sua maneira:

  - `explicitOriginalTarget` no FF (que ainda assim precisa de um hack, pois ele me devolve o text-node clicado);
  - `relatedTarget` no Chrome;
  - e no IE... sei lá, tem tantas formas de fazer que resolvi usar todas e pegar qualquer uma que não seja nula.
- ao setar o foco no `blur` descobri não funciona no FF, e assim tive que usar um `setTimeout`
- e finalmente, pra avacalhar, o IE 8 não preserva a seleção (bem esse não era um requisito na minha pergunta... hehe), assim sendo, tive que salvar a seleção e restaurá-la depois de dar o foco de volta para o input.

## [Fiddle da solução](http://jsfiddle.net/DWLSH/4/)

### Referências/Material de pesquisa

- [When onblur occurs, how can I find out which element focus went *to*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499/when-onblur-occurs-how-can-i-find-out-which-element-focus-went-to)
- [How to re-focus to a text field when focus is lost on a HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605974/how-to-re-focus-to-a-text-field-when-focus-is-lost-on-a-html-form)
- [Is there a way to use event.preventDefault with focusOut? If not, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613804/is-there-a-way-to-use-event-preventdefault-with-focusout-if-not-why)

Answer (score 1):

## Resposta:

Não há como **evitar** isto.

Por comportamento padrão do navegador, se você clicar em outra coisa, seu foco é perdido, **porém** você pode **devolver** o foco utilizando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) desta forma:

```
$('sua_tabela tr').click(function(){
  $('seu_input').focus();
});
```

Você pode simplismente por `$('seu_input').focus();` no final do código que você tem para selecionar a tal linha da tabela, porém certifique-se que o `focus()` esteja executando no final do processo.